# Contar vários registros para o chart no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Como que faço para contar vários registros com Laravel?
Exemplo:
Tabela homicios, contar as colunas mes, data, cidade separadamente e gerar o gráfico no chart.

Gráfico 1:
Jan - X quantidade
Fev - X quantidade 
Etc

Gráfico 2:
Cidade A -  X  quantidade 
Cidade Z -  X quantidade
Etc

Gráfico 3
Período entre A até B - X quantidade

A função no controller:

```
public function index()
    {
      $total= Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $janeiro = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','01')
      ->count();

      $fevereiro = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','02')
      ->count();

      $marco = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','03')
      ->count();

      $abril = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','04')
      ->count();

      $maio = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','05')
      ->count();

      $junho = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','06')
      ->count();

      $julho = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','07')
      ->count();

      $agosto = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','08')
      ->count();

      $setembro = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','09')
      ->count();

      $outubro = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','10')
      ->count();

      $novembro = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','11')
      ->count();

      $dezembro = Homicidio::whereYear('data', date('Y'))
      ->whereMonth('data','12')
      ->count();

      $loanda = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '1')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $santa_isabel = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '2')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $planaltina = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '3')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $santa_monica = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '4')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $santa_cruz = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '5')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $querencia = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '6')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $sao_pedro = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '7')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $porto_rico = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '8')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $nova_londrina = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '9')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $marilena = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '10')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $itauna = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '11')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();

      $diamante_norte = Homicidio::where('cidade_id', '=', '12')
      ->whereYear('data',date('Y'))
      ->count();



      return view('home', compact('janeiro',
      'fevereiro',
      'marco',
      'abril',
      'maio',
      'junho',
      'julho',
      'julho',
      'agosto',
      'setembro',
      'outubro',
      'novembro',
      'dezembro',
      'total',
      'loanda',
      'santa_isabel',
      'planaltina',
      'santa_monica',
      'santa_cruz',
      'querencia',
      'sao_pedro',
      'porto_rico',
      'nova_londrina',
      'marilena',
      'itauna',
      'diamante_norte'
    ));
    }
```

A view:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
  <!-- small box homicidios -->
  <div class="small-box bg-red">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>{!! $total !!}</h3>
      <p>Homicídios em {!! date('Y') !!}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
    </div>
    <a  href="#" id="link_homicidios" class="small-box-footer">
      Mais Informações <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- grafico homicidios -->
  <canvas id="grafico_homicidios" style="display:none;"></canvas>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 form-group">
  <!-- small box homicidios -->
  <div class="small-box bg-red">
    <div class="inner">
      <h3>3ª CIPM</h3>
      <p>Homicídios por Cidades</p>
    </div>
    <div class="icon">
      <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
    </div>
    <a  href="#" id="link_cidades" class="small-box-footer">
      Mais Informações <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- grafico homicidios -->
  <canvas id="grafico_cidades" style="display:none;"></canvas>
</div>

@section('javascript')

<script>
//exibir graficos

$( "#link_homicidios" ).click(function() {
  $( "#grafico_homicidios" ).toggle( "fast" );
});

$( "#link_cidades" ).click(function() {
  $( "#grafico_cidades" ).toggle( "fast" );
});

//Grafico Homicidios
var ctx = document.getElementById("grafico_homicidios");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [
          "Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun",
          "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"
         ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Homicídios',
            data: [
              {{ $janeiro }},
              {{ $fevereiro }},
              {{ $marco }},
              {{ $abril }},
              {{ $maio }},
              {{ $junho }},
              {{ $julho }},
              {{ $agosto }},
              {{ $setembro }},
              {{ $outubro }},
              {{ $novembro }},
              {{ $dezembro }}
            ],
            backgroundColor:
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ,
            borderColor:
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
//Final Grafico Homicidios

//Grafico Homicidios Cidades
var ctx = document.getElementById("grafico_cidades");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [
          "Diamante do Norte", "Itaúna do Sul", "Loanda", "Marilena", "Nova Londrina", "Planaltina do Paraná",
          "Porto Rico", "Querência do Norte", "St. Cruz M.C.", "St. Isabel I.", "St. Mônica", "São Pedro"
         ],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Homicídios',
            data: [
              {{ $diamante_norte }},
              {{ $itauna }},
              {{ $loanda }},
              {{ $marilena }},
              {{ $nova_londrina }},
              {{ $planaltina }},
              {{ $porto_rico }},
              {{ $querencia }},
              {{ $santa_cruz }},
              {{ $santa_isabel }},
              {{ $santa_monica }},
              {{ $sao_pedro }}
            ],
            backgroundColor:
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ,
            borderColor:
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ,
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
//Final Grafico Homicidios

</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: Se fez algum código? Se tem alguma SQL que represente isso? como você está desenvolvendo seu sistema?

Comment: Consegui fazer no modo gambiarra, fiquei gigante a função. Vou jogar como resposta abaixo e veja se consegue melhorar o código por favor.

Comment: Editei a resposta com o controller e a view, acho q da pra ter uma noção

Comment: Bom, não vejo melhorias no seu código, talvez um otimização com apenas uma SQL e depois em memória separar os dados ... talvez!

Comment: Pois é, a dúvida seria como melhorar o sql com menos consultas memso

Comment: Poderia fazer um GroupBy com Where por ano? o que acha!